# Retrieving original item from QAbstractItemModel subclass

Tags: qt, model-view

I need to implement a QAbstractListModel subclass so i can use a QListView with a domain class of our project.

The documentation covers nicely what methods i have to provide, but what baffles me is that there is no obvious way to retrieve the original object for a specific QModelIndex.

What i am looking for is something like this:

```
model MyModel<MyDomainEntity>(listOfDomainEntities);
model.item(someIndexComputedFromSelection); // Should return a MyDomainEntity
```

or

```
MyDomainEntity ent = model.data(someIndexComputedFromSelection, Qt::ItemRole)
                          .value<MyDomainEntity>();
```

But i can't find any easy way to do that, besides implementing these model methods myself. Am i missing something?

Comment: Since `QAbstractItemModel::item` doesn't exist, what do you expect other than implementing it yourself? The `data()` method should be implemented by you, and the code you show in the second line should work as long as the implementation is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to plug the `MyDomainEntity` into the `QMetaType` system. This will automatically make `QVariant` support it as well. And that's all you need for the code in your question to work.

All you need is:

```
// Interface
struct MyDomainEntity {
   int a;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyDomainEntity)

int main() {
   QVariant f;
   f.setValue(MyDomainEntity{3});
   Q_ASSERT(f.value<MyDomainEntity>().a == 3);
}
```

It also makes `QVariant` able to carry Qt containers of your type, e.g. `QList<MyDomainEntity>`.

Comment: It has no be noted that Qt::ItemRole doesn't exist either and a substitute has to be added to the model subclass. Qt reserves a couple of integers, so you should choose one that has a value of 256 or higher (for Qt5: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum).

Comment: @LucaFülbier Should all answers add a disclaimer "Whatever you wrote in your question that's made up, is for you to implement"? I mean, you chose to mix C++ with pseudocode - hopefully you know which is which?

Comment: Why wouldn't i add additional information for people who might have the same problem?